# Should I use a definite article in this sentence?

Tags: definite-article

I wrote:

> Birds are some of the most beautiful and inspiring creatures in the world. They fly freely in sky. They are always among trees and flowers.

A native speaker corrected it to "the trees". We don't speak of specific trees. Then why a definite article is needed?

Comment: ... in **the** sky...   No article is needed before **trees**.

Comment: @tromano he says he added it because "among " requires it!

Comment: **the** is not incorrect before **trees**, but it is not required. **The trees** in that case would be understood to mean "the trees one encounters".

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence should read

> They are always among **the** trees and **the** flowers.

It is idiomatic. For example, to say

> I ran through trees in the forest.

would be understood to mean you knocked down a bunch of trees, whereas

> I ran through *the* trees in the forest.

means you ran *among* the trees.

In the same way

> They were dancing among **the** flowers.
>   She was picking flowers and counting **the** petals.

Both of your sentences

> They are always among trees and flowers.
>   They are always among **the** trees and flowers.

are understandable and mean the same.

"The" refers to the specific group one has in mind, "We brought **the** presents for our friends" is a specific group of presents. "The trees" in this case would be interpreted as the trees near the birds, where they are flying around since they wouldn't be in trees on the other side of the world. "The trees, the birds, and the flowers of Yosemite make it unique" since they are specific groups to Yosemite.

The use of "the" is not necessary, but is nuanced to a native speaker.

This is different to "We ran into opposition" means someone conceptually opposed you about *something* versus "We ran into **the** opposition" which means you physically ran into the people who oppose you.

Comment: When we don't have specific trees in mind, how is "the" interpreted?

Comment: Added to my answer